# The activate() method doesn't return the activated sheet in xlwings on assignment

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlwings

I'm writing a program to convert Excel (.xlsx) files to json files using `Python 3.5` and `xlwings 0.10.0`. Everything is working great except I ran into a hiccup when trying to add an option for iterating over the sheets.

```
import xlwings as xw

wb = xw.Book('myfile.xlsx')
for s in wb.sheets:
    sheet = s.activate()
    print(sheet.range(1, 1))
```

This simplified code snippet sums up my problem.
In `xlwings` [documentation](http://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html) it is stated that the `activate()` method activates the sheet *and* returns it. Following that logic I would expect `sheet = s.activate()` to assign the current iterated and activated sheet to the variable `sheet`. Yet it throws an `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'range'` error when executing the last line (`sheet` returns None instead of the activated sheet).

What worked for me was separating the sheet activation and assignment:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book('myfile.xlsx')

for s in wb.sheets:
    s.activate()
    sheet = s
    print(sheet.range(1, 1))
```

I'd like to find out why the first snippet doesn't work and the second does.

If I have overlooked something basic I should know, please feel free to point that out since I'm quite new to development.

Comment: This is a bug report rather than a classic stackoverflow quesiton, I've opened an issue here: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/642

Comment: I wasn't sure where to go with this since I just might be missing something. Thank you!